# Show Selected value in drop down list on updating in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am hard coding Gender drop down as it has only two values and it will never be changed.Saving a data base hit.

How do show the selected value on the Edit view so the user can see which gender was selected and easily update it.

Create View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "1"},
new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "2"}
}, "Select")
```

Comment: You have a property name `Departments` that you want to set the value as either `1` or `2` to represent "Male" or "Female"?

Comment: Sorry Didn't understood

Comment: What you should have is a property named `Gender` which is typeof `string` (or better an `enum`) and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" } }, "select")` (but even better, your `SelectList` should be generated in the controller, not the view). And if you want to pre-select the option to display, then set the value of `Gender` to either `Male" or "Female" in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: You mean @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" } }, "select") on Edit and create right

Comment: Exactly. For the `Create()` method, you do not set a value for the property (so the `"select"` option is chosen), but for the `Edit()` method, the value will be either `"Male"` or `"Female"` and the corresponding option will be selected. You also need the `[Required]` attribute on the property, and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)` in the view.

Comment: Understood,how do I mark you solution as the answer.

Comment: I haven't added an answer yet :) - but will do so in 30 min or so (I was a little confused what you were doing hence my first comment)

Comment: Ok.Have used your code and it works fine on Create and edit View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little confusing why you are binding a value of `1` or `2` to a property named `Department` to represent the values "Male" and "Female". I'll assume that you really want to bind to a property named `Gender`.

Ideally, that property should be typeof `string` or an enum so that its stored as "Male" or "Female" (the values "1" or "2" wont have much meaning to anyone else).

In addition, you should be generating the `SelectList` in the controller and passing it to the view (preferably) using a view model or a `ViewBag` property.

```
public class PersonVM
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; } // or use an enum
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenderList { get; set; }
}
```

In the GET method

```
PersonVM model = new PersonVM()
{
    GenderList = new SelectList(new string[]{ "Male", "Female" }),
    Gender = // set this in an Edit method so the correct option is selected
}
// or if not using a view model - ViewBag.GenderList = new SelectList(new string[]{ "Male", "Female" });
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderList, "-select-")
// or if not using a view model - @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, (SelectList)ViewBag.GenderList, "-select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)
```